# How does one reference work in Oxford Style for a Website without an Author or a Date of Publication?

Tags: citations

How do you reference work, Oxford Style, for a Website without an Author or a Date of Publication?

Comment: For material found on a specific web site:

11. Australian Bureau of Statistics, Building approvals, Australia, cat. no. 8731.0, ABS Ausstats, 2004, retrieved 3 November 2004, ‹http://www.abs.gov.au/Ausstats/abs%40.nsf/mf/8731.0? OpenDocument›.

This can be found at: http://www.deakin.edu.au/current-students/study-support/study-skills/handouts/oxford-docnote.php

Comment: What's the cat. no. 8731.0, ABS Ausstats? Is that the 'Name of site sponsor'?

Comment: That's the full description of the online citation. It seems to be the name of the site's sponsor which is australian statistics.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the "Oxford Style" guide and therefore do not believe that there is a single "standard" style. I think [Oxford style](http://guides.is.uwa.edu.au/Oxford) has a footnote in text citation and a reference list. This makes it similar to Chicago style. While I do not have the CMS to check, [Prudue OWL](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/949/01/) has a nice comparison of MLA, APA, and CMS (all of which have comprehensive and standardized style guides). In CMS it doesn't seem to be a problem since you are using a footnote for the in text citation and the reference list doesn't require an author or date for webpages.